Correct way to take Oracle Data Pump - expdp, impdp
I am trying to take few rows on oracle linux and windows 10 both of them running Oracle 21c XE Import & Export using expdp & impdp but I faced issues. Both db configurations are identical.
In linux I am able to export 2 rows selectively, in windows I am not able to export any rows selectively.
Then I was aiming to import 2 rows back to the table.
The data is as follows:

SQL> select count(*) from account_balance;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         4

SQL> SELECT ROWID, AB.* FROM ACCOUNT_BALANCE AB;

ROWID              KEY_1            CURRENT_BALANCE
------------------ ---------------- ----------------
AAASyQAAMAAAAHrAAA 0000500521000111 12000
AAASyQAAMAAAAHrAAB 0000500521000112 56000
AAASyQAAMAAAAHrAAD 0000500521000114 36700
AAASyQAAMAAAAHsAAA 0000500521000113 679000

SQL> DELETE FROM ACCOUNT_BALANCE WHERE KEY_1 = '0000500521000111';

1 row deleted.

SQL> DELETE FROM ACCOUNT_BALANCE WHERE KEY_1 = '0000500521000113';

1 row deleted.

SQL> select count(*) from account_balance;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         2

SQL> SELECT ROWID, AB.* FROM ACCOUNT_BALANCE AB;

ROWID              KEY_1            CURRENT_BALANCE
------------------ ---------------- ----------------
AAASyQAAMAAAAHrAAB 0000500521000112 56000
AAASyQAAMAAAAHrAAD 0000500521000114 36700

SQL> desc account_balance;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 KEY_1                                     NOT NULL CHAR(16)
 CURRENT_BALANCE                                    CHAR(16)

SQL> SELECT table_name, owner FROM all_tables WHERE table_name='ACCOUNT_BALANCE' ORDER BY owner, table_name;

TABLE_NAME           OWNER
-------------------- --------------------
ACCOUNT_BALANCE      L3DBA



Export Query Used (Oracle-Linux):
expdp L3DBA@VIRTUAL_PDB1 tables=account_balance directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR QUERY=\"WHERE KEY_1=\'0000500521000113\'\" dumpfile=acct_bal_0000500521000113_bkp.dmp logfile=acct_bal_0000500521000113_bkp.log;
expdp L3DBA@VIRTUAL_PDB1 tables=account_balance directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR QUERY=\"WHERE KEY_1=\'0000500521000111\'\" dumpfile=acct_bal_0000500521000111_bkp.dmp logfile=acct_bal_0000500521000111_bkp.log;

Export Query Used (Windows-10):
expdp L3DBA@DESKTOP_XEPDB1 tables=account_balance directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR QUERY=\"WHERE KEY_1=\'0000500261000112\'\" dumpfile=acct_bal_bkp20230504_3.dmp logfile=acct_bal_bkp20230504_3.log;
LRM-00111: no closing quote for value ''000050026'

Import Query Used (Oracle-Linux):
impdp L3DBA@VIRTUAL_PDB1 tables=account_balance directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=acct_bal_0000500521000113_bkp.dmp logfile=acct_bal_0000500521000113_imp.log CONTENT=DATA_ONLY TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=APPEND EXCLUDE=INDEX,CONSTRAINT;
impdp L3DBA@VIRTUAL_PDB1 tables=account_balance directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=acct_bal_0000500521000111_bkp.dmp logfile=acct_bal_0000500521000111_imp.log CONTENT=DATA_ONLY TABLE_EXISTS_ACTION=APPEND EXCLUDE=INDEX,CONSTRAINT;

What I noticed is that while I was connected to the DB while importing select rows importing was paused. Same was not in the case when I tried to import Full Table (same table).
What might be the cause of this?
Additionally how do I correctly perform expdp and impdp on windows system for same data?

Not related to your issue, but why are you storing a numeric value like a balance as a string; and why are you storing anything as char rather thanvarchar2? For your export are you sure the whole command is on one line, not split onto two after the ..0026? And for import what does "importing was paused" mean? (Maybe you just haven't committed the deletes?) This should probably be two questions - but neither issue is on-topic for this site really.

@AlexPoole Thanks, one issue where import was getting paused (running for 10+ mins) was due to a commit issue. For the export issue, the whole command is on one line. Written on notepad and pasted on the terminal without new line. I overlooked the column datatypes while creating.

Windows in particular is quite picky about quotes and the like on the command line. For me, I just throw things in a PARFILE to make life easier
par.dat
=======
tables=account_balance 
directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR 
QUERY="WHERE KEY_1='0000500261000112'" 
dumpfile=acct_bal_bkp20230504_3.dmp 
logfile=acct_bal_bkp20230504_3.log;

expdp user/pass parfile=par.dat


Thanks, able to export using PARFILE. Another thing the query worked on CMD, and Git Bash but not on powershell (which was the default for Windows terminal). Following query worked for me expdp L3DBA/l3secret@DESKTOP_XEPDB1 tables=account_balance directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR QUERY=\"WHERE KEY_1='0000500261000114'\" dumpfile=acct_bal_bkp20240706.dmp logfile=acct_bal_bkp20240706.log;
